# Is it acceptable to say "I don't have a clue" meaning "I don't know" in formal English?

Tags: formality

I'm a non-native speaker. When I was a student of English my teachers mentioned this answer was to be avoided in formal situations, except for its literal meaning. Years later I heard it twice, as a reply to questions, in formal lectures at my professional congresses. What I want to know is whether it is proper to answer that way, when you me
an "I don't know" or "I have no idea", in formal spoken or written English.

Comment: There is what can be said, what should be said, what was said, and what was heard. When you, OP, ask such questions, my question to you is "acceptable to whom?" Who is the audience? What level of acceptance would properly answer your question? On target: Is the statement grammatically correct? Yes. Is the statement understood by an audience in grammar, content, and context? Yes. Is the statement allowed to be stated as such? Yes. Given this, what do you want to know?

Comment: It may sound a bit informal, but the usage is correct. Now, when you say "formal", I imagine you're talking about high-collar, CEO level or maybe even Royal Family formal, at which point it's less about being rude and more not making yourself look like an unreliable man (that is, you want to avoid "I don't know" and its variations entirely)

Comment: ODO: *have a clue* [usually with negative] **informal** Know about something or about how to do something: *I didn’t have a clue what was happening* (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clue) Note the usage note I've emphasized above: **informal** HTH.

Comment: @Kris Then, the implied question here is kinda why is it being used in a lecture? The OP obviously understands that it's considered informal - that's the reason they're asking the question!

Comment: @SrJoven I'm a non-native speaker. When I was a student of English my teachers mentioned this answer was to be avoided in formal situations, except for its literal meaning.  Years later I heard it twice in formal lectures. What I want to know is whether it is proper to answer that way, when you mean I have no idea, in formal spoken and written English.

Comment: The problem with answering your question is in the response to "who's the audience" In general, the statement is not *formal*. It doesn't mean it's not something people say, though. As mentioned in the comments, the expression as written, or similar "I don't know", is not one that would be expected in formal writing. That is to say, while it may be found in formal writing, it would be expected that another euphemism would be used, such as "cannot be determined", unless quoting someone.

Comment: @SrJoven I'm a cardiologist. I've heard it during presentations in International Congresses, and that's one of the situations I would consider "formal speech".  Professionally, I would consider "formal writing" when I write a letter to a person I've never met or I've met a few times in a professional setting. I heard the sentence recently and it immediately rang a bell. (What one of my English Teachers once said.)

Comment: Back to my original comment: What answer could be given to your question that you'd accept? Even if an answer said, "that's not formal" and even the comments here say as much, it's just people expressing opinions: their own or cited from elsewhere. If the statement was used in what you considered a formal setting, and the audience didn't express displeasure in the terminology utilized, one could reasonably assume that the statement was accepted -- as stated -- in a formal setting. Even if authoritatively asserted that the usage was "incorrect", it changes nothing that it was used.

Comment: I thought there would be no difficulty saying whether a word or phrase usage is formal or informal. There are a lot of questions here about the subject and they have been answered and upvoted. What's so wrong with mine?

Comment: I don't know what else to say that I haven't already said twice. The question has been answered in the comments. Clarification to the question has been suggested and I, specifically, asked for "what answer would be one that you'd accept?". What problem does the answer to your question solve, and what level of authoritative will be required to answer your question in light of the usage being accepted in a context that you would consider formal?

Comment: @SrJoven  I would accept any answer that is upvoted most.  Preferably, one that has references and goes straight to the point instead of adding unnecessary quotes.  Basically it is a "yes or no" question.

Comment: Please update your question with the information regarding what constitutes an acceptable answer to you. Comments are not intended to be forever and most people will only observe the top five comments anyway. [help]

Comment: I believe this is a very subjective question, there can be no "right" answer. Much depends on the speaker's self confidence, experience, position and his audience. If, for example, an eminent detective is asked, one to one, who is the murderer in an unsolved case he might well admit to not having a clue, despite all his investigative attempts. Then again, he might consider that same phrase to be unprofessional at a press conference, he'll suspect that the reporters will probably massacre his reputation in the papers the next day and will opt for a more open-ended answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chief of Detectives in a major city's police force is at a press conference, reporting on progress solving several mysterious disappearances of prominent people.  Minutes earlier, the CoD and his detectives have bemoaned among themselves that they don't have a clue.  According to your English teacher, the CoD can say, in the press conference, that he doesn't have a clue. But does he say that? Of course not!

A person whose opinion counts for something can use the phrase "don't have a clue" only **when it is safe** -- for example, when she is among peers who are also friends, none of whom are likely to stab her in the back later.

As for the International Congress where you heard the phrase: if it was in a formal presentation, I'll bet that it was about an aspect of the subject in which everyone would agree that no one had a clue or it was a dismissive answer to a question the answerer regarded as stupid.

MDs should be especially wary of using the phrase if a hypochondriac could be anywhere within earshot.

In situations where nothing is at stake, "I don't have a clue" is OK.  Such situations are unlikely to be formal.

Comment: It took me a year to see a decent answer here.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In most spoken language, as you've noticed, it will be quite acceptable, except probably in technical settings.  However for written language, it's only really acceptable in informal situations.

For example, in a story, a tweet, or blog post, no matter the audience, it would be acceptable, but in a formal letter, technical paper, or legal document it would not be acceptable.

Comment: The defendant responded 'I don't have a clue!' Sorry, 'I don't know!'